# composition c++, am i doing it right?

Tags: c++, class, aggregation, composition

this time i wrote a program all by my damn self but I just want to make sure I did it right and if anybody has any suggestions to improve it in anyway

a)Define and implement the Die class depicted by the following UML diagram to create an ADT for one die (singular of dice) with faces showing values between 1 and the numberOfFaces on the die.  Define a two-parameter constructor with defaults of 6 faces and 1 for face value.   Define and implement a roll() method to simulate the rolling of the die by generating a random number between 1 and numberOfFaces and storing that number in faceValue.  Provide an accessor to return the die’s face value and a print() method to print the die’s face value.

b) Use composition to design a PairOfDice class, composed of two six-sided Die objects. Create a driver program with a main() function to rolls a PairDice object 1000 times, counting then displaying the number of snake eyes (i.e. two ones) and box cars (i.e. two sixes) that occur.

die.h

```
#ifndef DIE_H
#define DIE_H

class die {

private:
    int numberOfFaces;
    int faceValue;
public:
    die();
    die(int, int);
    int roll();
    void print();
```

};
 #endif

die.cpp

```
#include "die.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
#include<random>
using namespace std;

die::die()
{
    numberOfFaces=6;
    faceValue=1;
}

die::die(int numOfFaces, int faceVal)
{
    numberOfFaces=numOfFaces;
    faceValue=faceVal;
}

int die::roll()
{
    faceValue=rand()%numberOfFaces;
    return faceValue;
}

void die::print()
{
    cout << faceValue << endl;
}
```

pairOfDice.h

```
#include "die.h"
#ifndef PAIROFDICE_H
#define PAIROFDICE_H

class pairOfDice :
    public die
{
private:
    die die1;
    die die2;
    int value1;
    int value2;
    int total;
public:
    pairOfDice();
    int roll();
};

#endif
```

pairOfDice.cpp

```
#include "pairOfDice.h"

pairOfDice::pairOfDice()
    :die(6,1)
{
    value1=1;
    value2=1;
    total=value1+value2;
}

int pairOfDice::roll()
{
    value1=die::roll();
    value2=die::roll();
    total=value1+value2;
    return total;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include"pairOfDice.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int rolls=0, total=0, snakeEyes=0, boxCars=0;
    pairOfDice dice;

    while(rolls<1000)
    {
        total = dice.roll();

        if(total==2)
            snakeEyes++;
        else if(total==6)
            boxCars++;
        else
            rolls++;
    }

    cout << rolls << " " << snakeEyes << " " << boxCars << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is probably more suitable for http://codereview.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: one more thing, when i seed the rand function, i get really huge numbers that are greater than 1000. otherwise, it works fine but i would preferably need different results each time.

Comment: oh thank you !! i wasnt aware of that section. im stil fairly new to the site, i apologize